# Divide ul into multiple columns

Tags: jquery

In this forum I found a jquery solution to divide a long ul into multiple columns. The post is a bit old and after a few days still no answer, therefor I'm starting a new topic.

The problem is that when the last column have a few li items the li are placed at the bottom instead of the top.
Something like this:

```
columnA       columnB
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>     <li></li>
<li></li>     <li></li>
```

The code I use is this:

```
  var col_max_height = 15; //Max Items per column
  var col_width = 175; //Pixels
  var col_height = 18; //Pixels
  $('.categories ul li ul').each(function() {
    $(this).find('li').each(function(index){
      column = parseInt(index/col_max_height);
      $(this).css('margin-left', column * col_width + 'px')
        if(column > 0) {
        $(this).css('margin-top', (index - (col_max_height * column)  + 1) * -col_height + 'px').addClass('col_'+column);
    }
   });
  });
```

As you can see the code places the li items starting at `margin-top:-270px`.
I want to start at `margin-top:0` and then further down.

I can't see what to do for that...

Comment: Can you please add associated HTML or link to sketch/fiddle?

Comment: This seems like a bad way to do it. You can use "float: left" instead and just have each new item flow to the next line. That way you don't need to use margin-top at all.

Comment: Are you unable to use HTML5 column-count ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [CSS columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#the-multi-column-model) and screw older browsers (they can live with a single column):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C9M76/1/)

```
ul {
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  columns: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the:

```
 if(column > 0)
```

or changing it to:

```
 if(column >= 0)
```

That should do the trick... if not, the problem seems to happen when column is zero and some margin-top calculations mislead that case.